# Strange OpenLayers 3 behaviour when trying to show a polygon on the map

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am experiencing a very strange thing in OpenLayers 3, and maybe someone could help me solve this issue. I am trying to show a polygon on the map, based on an array of coordinates, using the following functions:

```
Map.prototype.addLocation = function(location) {
   var polygon, i, z;

   if (typeof location.geometry === 'undefined') return false;

   for (i = 0; i < location.geometry.length; i++) {
        for (z=0; z < location.geometry[i].length; z++) location.geometry[i][z]=this.transformProjection(location.geometry[i][z]);
   }

   polygon=this.createFeature('polygon', 'location', location.geometry);
   polygon.values_.content.push(location.data);
   this.map.getView().fit(polygon.getGeometry().getExtent(), this.map.getSize()); 
}

Map.prototype.createFeature = function(type, group, geometry, layer) {
    var _geometry, feature;

    if (typeof layer == 'undefined') layer='main';
    if (type == 'polygon') _geometry=new ol.geom.Polygon(geometry);
    else if (type == 'point') _geometry=new ol.geom.Point(geometry);
    else return false;

    this.features.entities++;

    feature=new ol.Feature({
        geometry: _geometry,
        type: type,
        group: group,
        state: 0,
        content: []
    });
    feature.setId(this.features.entities);
    feature.setStyle(this.styles[type][group].default);

    this.layers[layer].getSource().addFeature(feature);
    this.features[type][group].push(feature);

    return feature;
}

Map.prototype.transformProjection = function(coordinates, from, to) {
    if (typeof from == 'undefined') from = 'EPSG:4326';
    if (typeof to == 'undefined') to = 'EPSG:3857';

    return ol.proj.transform(coordinates, from, to);
}
```

Basically, what's happening here, is that `Map.addLocation` gets called, with the parameter set to an object, which has the `geometry` property, containing an array of coordinates. It should convert the coordinates from lat/lon to the projection OL3 uses, add the feature to the default basic layer, and then try to fit the polygon in the viewport of the map div. What happens is really strange:

If I leave the code as it is, the map gets rendered, but no polygon is drawn on it, and no Javascript errors appear. But if I change the `this.map.getView().fit()` methods parameters, to something invalid, for example, to `this.map.getView().fit(polygon, this.map.getSize());`, the map is rendered, the polygon is drawn on the map, and I get an error: **AssertionError: Assertion failed: invalid extent or geometry**. If I remove the line completly, no error appears, but the polygon doesn't get drawn anyways.

I can't figure out what's causing this, as if I use the `this.map.getView().fit()` method correctly, I do not get any errors, but I also don't get the desired result. If I use it erroneuosly, I get the desired result, but the appearing error, renders everything in my code useless afterwards. Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: I suggest you to start debugging. Inside `createFeature` for example: `console.log(type, group, geometry, layer)`

Comment: Yep, found the error, I was transforming the projection twice of a later point I was adding, and that was the thing causing the error.